# Creating multiple rows in a dataframe with a single sampling command

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, sampling

I want to create a dataframe consisting of hundred rows, each row representing the output of this code:

```
sample(seq(100, 1000),20,replace=T)
```

Is there a way to order R to repicate the above code 100 times and create a dataframe out of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `replicate`

```
t(replicate(100, sample(seq(100, 1000),20,replace=T)))
```

Comment: thanks that's it. Thanks for responding so quickly. Is there a simpler way of adding row names to it besides creating a column consisting of a vector from 1 to 100 and doing `cbind`?

Comment: I figured out this way: `as.data.frame(t(replicate(100, sample(seq(100, 1000),20,replace=T))),rownames=T)`